# Automatically creating a database when starting YugabyteDB container

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm trying to run YugabyteDB in docker and want to create a dababase automatically as in PostgreSQL with the environment var `POSTGRES_DB`. Couldn’t do it with command or postgres environment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with YugabyteDB and that environment variable.

You can use an additional service that is used just for this job, something like:

```
  create-db:
      image: yugabytedb/yugabyte:latest
       command: ysqlsh -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on -h yb-tserver-0 -e -c 'create database demo'
      deploy:
      restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
      depends_on:
      - yb-tserver-0
```

because you want to run this only once, even when you have many yb-tservers.